# How can you pushdown predicates to Cassandra or limit requested data when using Pyspark / Dataframes?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

For example on [docs.datastax.com](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkDataFrames.html) we mention :

```
table1 = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="kv", keyspace="ks").load()
```

and its the only way I know, but lets say that I want to load only the last one million entries from this table. I don't want to load the whole table in memory every time, especially if this table has for example, over 10 million entries.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you asking? I'm confused as to what your goal is.

Comment: My goal is to load data from table faster into a DataFrame.I am asking if its possible to load partially data or any other way from a data source's table instead of reading the whole table as stated in the question.

Answer (score 4):

While you can't load data faster. You can load portions of the data or terminate early. Spark DataFrames utilize catalyst to optimize it's underlying query plans enables it to take some short cuts.

For example calling `limit` will allow Spark to skip reading some portions from the underlying DataSource. These would limit the amount of data read from Cassandra by canceling tasks from being executed.

Calling filter, or adding filters can be utilized by the underlying Datasource to help restrict the amount of information actually pulled from Cassandra. There are limitations on what can be pushed down but this is all detailed in the documentation.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#pushing-down-clauses-to-cassandra

Note all of this is accomplished by simply doing further api calls on your DataSource once you call it. For example

```
val df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(table="kv", keyspace="ks")
  .load()

df.show(10) // Will compute only enough tasks to get 10 records and no more
df.filter(clusteringKey > 5).show() //Will pass down the clustering predicate to C*
```

Comment: So the first instruction is probably the standard way of loading data from Cassandra : "val df = sqlContext....load()". So even after calling load() the response time is still instant. Then I am calling df.count() and that's the lazy computation that is starting. I realized another thing, is if I applied a filter lets say to retrieve entries from the last few days (30% of total), the execution is even longer than without filter(where condition). The problem I have is that I have too much data in one single table, what I should do is try to split the data in days or week instead of months.

Comment: very helpful explanation...better than the documentation