# How to pushdown limit predicate for Cassandra when you use dataframes?

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have large Cassandra table. I want to load only 50 rows from Cassandra.
Following code

```
val ds = sparkSession.read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map("table" -> s"$Aggregates", "keyspace" -> s"$KeySpace"))
      .load()
      .where(col("aggregate_type") === "DAY")
      .where(col("start_time") <= "2018-03-28")
      .limit(50).collect()
```

Following code pushes both predicates from `where` methods, but not limit one. Is it true that whole data (1 million of records) being fetched? If not, why run time of this code and code without `limit(50)` roughly the same.

Comment: Just a guess: if you actually have less than 50 records meeting the predicate - Spark has to go through the whole table in order to check if there is more

Comment: @dk14 no, it's not the case, more than 10k records meets the predicate

Comment: `limit` doesn't translate to CQL's limit by default. However, if you work with underlying RDD, you can `asInstanceOf[CassandraRDD]` where specially defined `limit` method is available for CQL. See the edited answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike Spark Streaming, Spark itself is trying to preload as much data as it can, as fast as it can so to be able operate on it in parallel. So preloading is lazy, but greedy when it's triggered. There are cassandra-conector specific factors however:

- [Automatic predicate pushdown](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#automatic--predicate-pushdown-and-column-pruning) of **valid** "where" clauses.
- According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41009202/1809978) `limit(...)` is not translated to CQL's `LIMIT`, so then its behavior depends on how many fetching jobs are created after enough data is downloaded. Quote:

> calling limit will allow Spark to skip reading some portions from the
>   underlying DataSource. These would limit the amount of data read from
>   Cassandra by **canceling tasks from being executed**.

Possible solutions:

- DataFrame limits could be partially managed by limiting `numPartitions` and data exchange rate ([`concurrent.reads` and other params](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md)). If you're okay with n ~ 50 "in most cases", you could also limit something like `where(dayIndex < 50 * factor * num_records)`.
- There is a way to set CQL `LIMIT` through `SparkPartitionLimit`, which is directly affecting every CQL request ([see more](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/979ecbe77f520c382a5e44327cd59b33630df6b3/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/CassandraLimit.scala)) - keep in mind that requests are per-spark-partition. It's available in [CassandraRdd](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/CassandraRDD.scala#L102) extension class, so you would have to convert to RDD first.

The code would be something like:

```
filteredDataFrame.rdd.asInstanceOf[CassandraRDD].limit(n).take(n).collect()
```

This would append `LIMIT $N` to every CQL-request. Unlike with `DataFrame`'s limit, if you specify CassandraRDD `limit` several times (`.limit(10).limit(20)`) - only last one is going to be appended. Also, I used `n` instead of `n / numPartitions + 1` as it (even if Spark and Cassandra partitions are one-to-one) might return less results per-partition. As a result, I had to add `take(n)` in order to cut `<= numPartitions * n` down to `n`.

**Warning** double-check that your `where`'s are translatable to CQL (using `explain()`) - otherwise `LIMIT` would be applied before filtering.

P.S. You could also try to run CQL directly using `sparkSession.sql(...)` ([like here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/1ed0667825f40cd1e1396f08c910d0c06c3890ce/spark-cassandra-connector/src/it/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/sql/CassandraSQLSpec.scala#L412)) and compare results.