# How can I filter directly in Cassandra before loading data into a Spark Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, spark-java

I want to filter data directly on Cassandra DB and load the filtered data using Spark Java. So far, I have only found `.select()` for selecting the rows and `.filter()` for filtering data **after** it has been loaded as a Dataset.

This is the code snippet so far:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local")
                .setAppName("")
                .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
                .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")
                .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")
                .set("spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level", "ONE");

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> dataset = spark
                .read()
                .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .options(ImmutableMap.of("table", "my_table", "keyspace", "my_keyspace"))
                .select("col1", "col2")
                .load();

dataset = dataset.filter("col1 > 9");
```

Could someone please help with applying filters directly before loading the data?

Answer (score 1):

Spark along with [Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#predicate-pushdown-and-column-pruning) automatically takes care of reading only the data that is relevant to the job. This is done by Predicate Pushdown and Column Pruning. You can check the same in your
physical plan (use [explain](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain.html)).

This means Spark will only load the data necessary to complete the task at hand (this is one of the benefits of Lazy Evaluation, as Spark can tune the overall operations)

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534566/how-to-pushdown-limit-predicate-for-cassandra-when-you-use-dataframes) for more details

Ref: [Predicate Pushdown and Column Pruning](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#predicate-pushdown-and-column-pruning)

Answer (score 0):

With the [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector), you can apply a server-side filter using Spark SQL.

Here is an example for retrieving the name of a user:

```
Dataset<Row> user = spark.sql("SELECT name FROM users WHERE username = 'alice123'");
```